# Blend for Visual Studio 2013 - Unable to add event handler

Tags: visual-studio-2013, blend

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, with Blend, to play around with creating Windows 8 apps. I used Blend to add a button, but when I went to add the name of an event handler method to the button in Blend, all the textboxes pertaining to the different events were disabled.

Screenshot as follows:

[image: Contrast between the active textbox "Name" near the top, and the disabled textboxes that pertain to the event handler methods. The latter cannot be interacted with.]

*Contrast between the active textbox "Name" near the top, and the disabled textboxes that pertain to the event handler methods. The latter cannot be interacted with.*

I am aware that I can add events in Visual Studio, but I was wondering if there is any reason why I can't do it in Blend.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Update: It looks like the issue is fixed in *Blend for Visual Studio 2015.*

Comment: Did you followed these steps? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294821.aspx.

Comment: @ckruczek Yeah, I get stuck on step 6 - I can't interact with the text boxes at all.

Comment: Just to be sure: Is the application running? Because if it is running Blend and VS will prevent any editing on the source code.

Comment: Definately not running. I can edit everything else fine.. Just not the event handlers. It really has got me stumped. I even successfully added an event handler from Visual Studio.

Comment: Could you add a image to your original question maybe?

Comment: Absolutely. Won't be a moment. Done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79479/discussion-between-ckruczek-and-brad-sullivan).

Comment: You may want to take a look for the chat I opened recently ;)

Comment: @ckruczek Since you expressed your interest on the issue (in chat): as per the updated post, Blend 2015 fixes the issue :)

Comment: Ohhh crap....but cool on the other. Thanks you remembered me ;) So have fun with the Blend :)

Comment: @ckruczek Haha no worries - Funny thing is, now I barely use Blend. I reckon just coding with XAML is so much better.